# Why are write/wrote, ride/rode but strike/struck?

Tags: verbs, past-tense, history

Why do *write* and *ride* change to *o* in the simple past (*wrote/rode*) but *strike* changes to *u* (*struck*)?

Comment: I know why the past tense of write, ride are not 'writed', 'rided'.

Comment: Perhaps to avoid confusion with the verb and noun "stroke".

Comment: There may also be influence from stick/stuck. Thought that is itself an enigma.

Comment: You need to learn the principal parts for irregular English verbs. write, wrote, written//ride, rode, ridden//strike, struck, struck//https://www.thoughtco.com/principal-parts-of-verb-english-grammar-1691679 [Grammar: Why do *we write* A, B, or C.]

Comment: @Peter We often get "They fall under such and such classification", but it's not often we get historical insight to "why" questions in language. [Since you know, please share why.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/587634/why-are-write-wrote-ride-rode-but-strike-struck#comment1472840_587634) (cf: "I know why the past tense of write, ride are not 'writed', 'rided'."

Comment: @Lambie that isn't really what the question is about.

Comment: @siride The wording was changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference does not go back to Old English: in that language, the verbs ancestral to *ride* and *strike* both used the same vowels in the past tense:

- ride = Old English **rīdan** (inf.), rād (1s past), ridon (plr past), ġeriden (pp.)
- strike = Old English **strīcan** (inf.), strāc (1s past), stricon (plr past), ġestricen (pp.)

They are categorized as "class 1" strong verbs. Even though these kinds of verbs are now taught as "irregular", they did originally follow patterns.

The vowel changed in the past tense of the descendant of *strīcan*, but not of *rīdan.* Two broad and distinct categories of explanations for why sounds change in language are regular sound laws, and analogy. The change of vowel in the past tense of *strike* does not appear to follow a regular sound law: for comparison, the sequence *āc* yields the expected outcome of *-oke* in the noun *spoke* from Old English *spāca.* Rather, the reason for the *u* in *struck* seems to be analogy with how other verbs formed their past tense; the analogy seems to have been mainly based on the other verbs having similar consonant patterns, but possibly partly based on them having similar meanings.

*A history of ablaut in the strong verbs from Caxton to the end of the Elizabethan period,* by H.T. Price (1910), has some discussion of this verb's forms. Price says that *stroke,* the regular outcome of the Old English form, is common up until about 1600, and from then on tends to get replaced by *strook* and *struck* ([page 23](https://books.google.com/books?id=Am8NAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA23)). Price's explanation is that *struck* was influenced by the past tense form *stuck* of the verb *stick.*

The Oxford English Dictionary entry for *strike* provides a record of forms that more or less agrees with Price's chronology, but does not discuss the irregular development.

The occurrence of *u* in *stuck* is itself hard to explain, as the forms of the verb "stick" have a complicated history.

There seem to be a small number of verbs ending in a velar consonant (/k/, /g/ or /ŋ/) which form past tenses with the vowel *u* (/ʌ/) in ways that don't go back to Old English. A handout on [Anthony Kroch's website](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/%7Ekroch/) titled "[The progress of /ʌ/](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/%7Ekroch/courses/lx310/handouts/handouts-09/ringe/prog-uh.pdf)" has a section "4. Early Modern English additions" which mentions the examples of *strung, dug, hung* in addition to *stuck* and *struck*, and in a later section mentions the development in modern English of "snuck" as a past tense of *sneak*.

"Survival of the Strongest", by Sherrylyn Branchaw (2010), suggests that innovative past tense forms with /ʌ/ are associated with verbs ending in a velar consonant due to the influence of verbs ending in *-ng* and *-nk* that were originally class 3 strong verbs, such as **sting**/**stung**  or **cling**/**clung** ([page 91](https://books.google.com/books?id=jzfjE14PniQC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=velar+%22struck%22+%22strike%22+ablaut&source=bl&ots=GUEzkQ2Iqb&sig=ACfU3U0CKDhd6_y0hxadiicL7BC2Zv07Ig&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvz9egzpb3AhUGD0QIHchoBJsQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=velar%20%22struck%22%20%22strike%22%20ablaut&f=false), *Studies in the History of the English Language V: Variation and Change in English Grammar and Lexicon: Contemporary Approaches*, edited by Robert A. Cloutier, Anne Marie Hamilton-Brehm, and William A. Kretzschmar, Jr.). Branchaw also says that the *s*-initial consonant clusters shared between some of these verbs made it easier for them to influence each other's past tense forms.